# Add common acronyms to FAQ?

Tags: discussion, faq

GORP, S&R, CG --- I've been hiking for years and I did not know what two of those mean. GORP evidently means peanuts (I thought it referred to all trail mix), and CG means center of gravity.

In some cases, like CG, I leans towards edits to spell it out, but in the case of GORP it *is* a widely known term which people may not be familiar with.  Would it be better to just add some common things like that to the FAQ?

Answer (score 4):

***Please avoid using abbreviations, especially on the main site. The following list is meant to be helpful if you encounter an unfamiliar abbreviation. It does not constitute an invitation to use these abbreviations.***

## TGO abbreviations

The following is a list of abbreviations common to Stack Exchange or to The Great Outdoors.

- CG/CoG — center of gravity
- CW — [community wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/);
  a post "owned" by the entire community rather than just the original 
  poster
- DV — downvote
- FGITW — [fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem),
  when several nearly-identical answers are posted within minutes
- GORP — good old raisins and peanuts, often used to refer to trail mix more generally.
- LNT — Leave No Trace
- MSO — [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), the “main meta” or “meta meta” site of the network, for discussing meta topics that affect all its sites
- OP — original poster; the author of a given question or answer
- OT — off-topic (usually; beware, some people use it for on-topic!)
- SE — [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/), our growing network of question-and-answer sites on diverse topics from software programming to cooking to photography and gaming
- S&R — Search & Rescue
- TGO — [The Great Outdoors](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com), this site
- UV — upvote
- VTC — vote to close
- SO — [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), the programming questions-and-answers site with which it all began

## Other abbreviations

The following is a list of abbreviations common to the Internet

- AFAIK — as far as I know
- AKA — also known as
- FYI — for your information
- IANAL — I am not a lawyer
- IIRC — if I recall correctly
- IIUC — if I understand correctly
- IMHO/IMnsHO — in my [not so] humble opinion
- IOW — in other words
- ISTR — I seem to remember/recall
- IYKWIM — if you know what I mean
- SPaG — spelling, punctuation, and grammar
- TPTB — The Powers That Be, the team that runs all the sites, as opposed to "mere mortals" such as regular users and moderators alike
- WP — [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia)